# R how to implement if else in apply instead of for loop

Tags: r, loops, if-statement, data.table, apply

EX Data:

```
Col1 Col2 
   1    a
   2    b
   3 null
   4    c
```

How do I change all elements of `Col2` that are `NULL` to some predefined value. My actual data is about 250,000 rows so a `for` loop would take too much time. I was thinking about some kind of `apply` / `ddply` and `ifelse` combination but I can't seem to get it working.

More specifically, how do I change the for loop to something more efficient

```
for(I in 1:n)
{
  if(col2(I) == NULL)
    col2(I) = x
    else...nothing happens
}
```

Comment: You only need `ifelse` if you only need to do it to a single column. `apply` will come in handy if you want to do the same thing to a lot of columns.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `ifelse` to change the value from `null` to, say, `XXX`

```
> dat <- read.table(h=T, text = "Col1 Col2 
  1     a
  2     b
  3     null
  4     c")
> dat
#   Col1 Col2
# 1    1    a
# 2    2    b
# 3    3 null
# 4    4    c
> dat$Col2 <- ifelse(dat$Col2 == 'null', 'XXX', dat$Col2)
> dat
#   Col1 Col2
# 1    1    1
# 2    2    2
# 3    3  XXX
# 4    4    3
```

An alternative way that may be easier to understand is

```
dat[,'Col2'] <- with(dat, ifelse(Col2 == 'null', 'XXX', Col2))
```

Furthermore, if you're dealing with factors and you want to change the name of a level,

```
> levels(dat$Col2)
## [1] "a"    "b"    "c"    "null"
> levels(dat$Col2)[4] <- "XXX"
> levels(dat$Col2)
## [1] "a"   "b"   "c"   "XXX"
```

Comment: Or if it's a true "null" value rather than just the word "null", then then use ifelse(is.null(dat$Col2), 'XXX', dat$Col2)

Comment: getting error $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: @MrFlick is right.  If the value is `NULL`, use `is.null`.  If `null`, it may be a factor level or character value.

Comment: @MathLover, you don't need to loop the data with this.  I think that my be why you got the error?

Comment: @RichardScriven Actually, your solution is more likety to work since  atomic vectors cannot have true `null` values, only `NA`. So testing with `== 'null'` will likely lead to the right result

Comment: @MathLover, he has loaded your example into a data frame called `dat`. You may have your data in individual vectors. If so, just remove the 3 `dat$`'s & the `ifelse` command should work.

Comment: It is interesting to note (at least for me b/c I didnt know before) that the `ifelse` as in your example code above, changes `Col2` from `factor` to `chr` (without warning or information) while the solution by @John Paul doesnt.

Answer (score 1):

Why not

```
Col2[Col2=="null"]<-"XXX"
```

Note - I don't think you can get a true `NULL` value in a `data.frame` like that.

#### Update for factors

In response to @beginneR,

If `Col2` is a `factor` you can do this to change it:

```
levels(Col2)<-c(levels(Col2),"XXX")
Col2[Col2=="null"]<-"XXX"
```

Comment: That's what I thought, too. But for the example code by @Richard, this doesnt work, because Col2 is `factor` and "XXX" is not a defined factor level. If it were a character variable, this would work.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an approach using `data.table`, which should scale pretty well.

The example below for 1 million rows, takes less than 1/10 of a second on my laptop.

```
# Load package data.table 
library(data.table)

# Set up data
Col1 <- rep(c(1,2,3,4), 250000)
Col2 <- rep(c("a", "b", "null", "c"), 250000)

# Define data as data.table
ex <- data.table(Col1, Col2)

# Substitute value "null" by "x" for variable "Col2"
ex[Col2=="null", Col2:="x"]
```

Comment: if `Col2` is `character`, then `df$Col2[df$Col2 == "null"] <- "x"`  takes 0.084s on my machine and if it is `factor`, `levels(df$Col2)[4] <- "x"` is even faster (0.030s) (based on your example data of 1e6 rows)

Answer (score 0):

How about using      replace()?

```
R:> Col1 <- c(1,2,3,4)
R:> Col2 <- c("a", "b", "null", "c")
R:> ex <- data.frame(Col1, Col2)
R:> ex
   Col1 Col2
1    1    a
2    2    b
3    3 null
4    4    c
R:> typeof(ex$Col2)
[1] "integer"
R:> ex$Col2 <- as.character(ex$Col2)
R:> typeof(ex$Col2)
[1] "character"
R:> ex$Col2 <- replace(ex$Col2, which(ex$Col2 == "null"), "some")
R:> ex
  Col1 Col2
1    1    a
2    2    b
3    3 some
4    4    c
R:>
```